# Face Pose estimation in OpenCV without 3D modelling

Tags: c++, opencv, position, head

I need to estimate the face pose of a person using OpenCV but I can't find any specific functions that is able to do so. I don't want to use 3D modelling as it is out of my project field.

Is there any specific way on doing so? Eg, obtaining the Yaw, Roll, Pitch value of a person?

Answer (score 0):

You can locate some landmarks of the face in your image using haar cascades or AAM, then use some predefined 3d estimation of where those selected points should be in the worldview and leave it to OpenCV SolvePnP to find the pose matrix.

Check out [this example](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2010/03/19/quick-and-easy-head-pose-estimation-with-opencv-w-code/)